# Negative user-defined type guards

Tags: typescript, type-narrowing

```
function isFish(pet: Fish | Bird): pet is Fish {
    return (<Fish>pet).swim !== undefined;
}
```

tells typescript that pet type is `Fish`

Is there a way to state the contrary, that the input parameter is NOT a Fish?

```
function isNotFish(pet: Fish | Bird): pet is not Fish {  // ????
       return pet.swim === undefined;
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the `Exclude` conditional type to exclude types from a union :

```
function isNotFish(pet: Fish | Bird): pet is Exclude<typeof pet, Fish>    
{ 
    return pet.swim === undefined;
}
```

Or a more generic version :

```
function isNotFishG<T>(pet: T ): pet is Exclude<typeof pet, Fish>    { 
    return pet.swim === undefined;
}
interface Fish { swim: boolean }
interface Bird { crow: boolean }
let p: Fish | Bird;
if (isNotFishG(p)) {
    p.crow
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using the same function, but the function just retuns `false`.

Comment: Do you mind sharing an example? Wouldn't that still return a Fish type when the thing is not a fish?